# Add themes in my Rails applications.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Hello,

how do I add themes to [startBootstrap](https://startbootstrap.com) in my Rails application?

please.

(Clean blog)

Comment: I suggest you do a web search and start reading Bootstrap theme tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to copy all the content from the template to your project
like css,js,code from html file